# python dictionary looping over multiple values and returning them as single list values for single key

Tags: python, dictionary

```
names={"animal":"cat","animal":"dog","animal":"rat","bird":"humming"}
names_dict={}
for k,v in names.items():
    names_dict.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)   
print (names_dict)
```

My desired output should be:

```
{'animal': ['rat','cat','dog'], 'bird': ['humming']}
```

but the output im getting is this

```
{'animal': ['rat'], 'bird': ['humming']}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Dictionaries keys should be unique...`print(names)` to check.

Comment: Your initial dictionary doesn't contain what you think it does, some of that information has already been lost. It's unclear where that's coming from, so this isn't solvable as posted; [edit] to provide more context, why do you think that's what you're starting with?

Comment: Thanks rakesh:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key in a Python dictionary should be unique. You have repeated the same key `'animal'` thrice, and Python retained the value of the *last*<sup>1</sup> animal key. From the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html),

> It is best to think of a dictionary as a set of key: value pairs, with the  requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary).

---

<sup>1. Note that *last* can also be quite vague. Depending on the Python version you have, it might be consistent but that cannot be generally guaranteed.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
names={"animal":"cat","animal":"dog","animal":"rat","bird":"humming"}
```

is exactly the same with this:

```
names={"animal":"rat","bird":"humming"}
```

When you add items to `dict`, if the key is already is in the dict, the value will be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in @Vijay M's answer, the key in python dictionaries should be unique. I guess you are looking for a solution like this one:

```
names = {"cat": "animal", "dog": "animal", "rat": "animal", "humming": "bird"}

names_dict={}
for k, v in names.items():
    names_dict.setdefault(v,[]).append(k)

print(names_dict)
```

Note that the values and the keys are swapped.

Hopefully, this helps.